# How to read contents of a (previosuly Win-XP system) HDD when plugged as simple additional drive under Win-7,

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-xp, partitioning, filesystems

Getting a new PC in 2010, I kept the HDD of my previous PC, in case...
And today it's the case: I'm looking for some old code I worked on in the past, then threw meantime because I thought it was obsolete, and finally now would be glad to retrieve!

I must add that I'm only a software developper, and don't have many skills about hardware. In addition the involved drive is an IDE one, while my current PC has only SATA available.
So I asked a PC-shop to plug my drive to some PC and let me search...

That's said, here is the issue.

- When it was the only drive on my old PC, this HDD was partitioned (NTFS) so in Windows Explorer it appeared as 2 different units C: and D:, and obviously C: was the system disk (Windows XP).
- Today at the shop, once plugged (to a Windows 7 system, if the information is useful) as a simple additional drive:

  - it keeps showing its 2 partitions when using the storage handler utility
  - but in Windows Explorer I don't see any distinction: in its currently affected unit (E:), the drive merely shows all folders (and root files) as if it was a unique container
  - and **at least one important (quantitatively) folder doesn't appear**, while I'm absolutely certain that it exists (so I suspect that some other ones may be hidden too)

You can now guess that I didn't either retrieved the folder I was specifically looking for, and you're right!

So my question: is there something that might explain why some folders are currently not visible, and is there any chance to remedy this?

In case it's useful: the drive is a Seagate ST360012A, 60Gbytes.
I can affirm it was fully functional at the time I stopped it.

Comment: Permissions?  Hidden attribute? Corrupted file system? Bad disk?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Nothing of that: as said in my question, this drive was fully functional when I stopped using it.

Comment: Is the folder a system folder? The user folder? Either there's something simple going wrong or the mounting process they used at the shop is arcane.

Comment: @Mast All folders I'm interested to (and that not appear) are simple ones, located in the 2nd partition, which was seen as D: (so not system nor user). Based on your remark "Either something simple... or... is arcane", I wonder if it could exist some documentation where I would find clearly exposed all the rules, exigences, and pitfalls about this kind of situation?